# Best bitmap compression for setting bits randomly

Tags: performance, algorithm, bitmap

I am looking for Bitmap compression algorithm which can allow me to generate bitmaps by setting random bits and I am concerned about amount of space bitmap takes in RAM e.g.

Uncompressed bitmap to store 1073741824 bits (Around 1 Billion bits) needs around 128 MB of space and I don't have that much space at all. I would like to do this in as much less space (RAM) as possible.

I looked at WAH, EWAH etc (haven't carefully read papers yet) at others but looks like they are stream compressions and setting bits randomly in compressed format of bitmap (while creating it) isn't possible (very expensive operation) e.g. if one wants to set 100th, 200th, 300th it is works, but if requirement is to set 100th, 200th, 105th, 3000th, 1999th then it isn't possible.

The information that which bit is set and which isn't set can only be obtained randomly in my case for all bits e.g. if I am doing some operation 1073741824 times, I need to set any bit based on operation results and they wouldn't be in increasing order.

Is this correct and are there alternatives ?

**Summary: Algorithm for creating a compressed bitmap while setting bits randomly.** No entropy/pattern information available. Distribution can be anything.

Aim: Best algorithm to save memory. **Reduce the memory taken by bitmap while creating it by setting random bits.**

Comment: How many bits will be set? That determines the total entropy and the minimum storage requirements. And can bits be set multiple times? How often will that happen?

Comment: Bits can just be set once but randomly

Comment: If 50% of all bits are randomly set you cannot compress at all. What do you do then? :) You *must* constrain the problem to fit it into less that 128 MB.

Comment: Yes, that would be worst case if 50% are evenly distributed (and we are not compressing with patterns) and we are using stream compression of run list sort. We cannot actually tell whether bits will form any pattern overall because we are getting them randomly.

Comment: @harold I updated question after your comments, does quad-tree still satisfy less memory and setting bits randomly ? I will check it and see whether it is useful.

Comment: Only if it's either very sparse or very dense. Quad-trees are excellent at not storing large uniform regions, but very bad at storing noise at 50%. So in short .. no, and nothing else can really do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no pattern is known beforehand, and you have little working memory, the following should do fine:

Tile the image into small sections (lines or rectangular tiles). The sections should be small enough that you can quickly uncompress, set bits and compress. They should be big enough to provide the encoder with enough data to actually encode (64KB?). You can use any compression algorithm at like, like Deflate or LZMA (7-zip).

Put incoming bits temporarily into a list. Once that list fills up (maybe 1MB of space taken?) you need to copy the bits to the sections of the bitmap. After doing that you can clear the list. The list is just a temporary buffer that allows to batch many updates per section into one decompress-compress cycle.

Before writing out the bits, sort them by section and position. That allows you to clear duplicates and to process all sections just once.

Note, that no guarantees can be made, that compression is even possible. If there are no compressible patterns, it is impossible to compress.

Answer (score 4):

We are getting good results with Roaring bitmaps: http://roaringbitmap.org/

Comment: Jar files are available on the maven repository or directly on GitHub : https://github.com/lemire/RoaringBitmap/releases

Comment: @Danel  sorry .but only sorce code download link i can see...i use eclipse can u give me ink of .jar download

Comment: Normally, you would not grab a jar file yourself but rather use a tool for that purpose. The standard tool for building Java projects is maven, of course, but all IDEs also support it. For example, under Eclipse, you just go to "add library" and choose "maven managed dependencies". IntelliJ does the same.  If you must do things manually, please browse the README.md file of the project, links are provided.